# Generate new GUID in SQL Server if one is not provided

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am updating my database to have a column for a GUID for each record in a table.

This table is populated by several different sources and some of them will not provide a GUID for new records.

How can I populate this column with a newid() on the DB side only if there was no value passed in for a new record?

Comment: Set the default for the column as `NEWID()`?

Comment: so if a value does not exist, then NEWID() will populate it and not overwrite it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

DO NOT I REPEAT DO NOT PLACE A DEFAULT COLUMN OF `NEWID()`. If you do the GUID you get will be completely random and if you have any sort of indexing on this column it will be useless. If you are going to do this you want to set the column default to be `NEWSEQUENTIALID ( )`

Kimberly Tripp has a [Great Article](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/) and another [Great Article](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/disk-space-is-cheap/) on this subject.

To implement `NEWSEQUENTIALID ( )` as a default:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(unq_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
 cola varchar(10));
```

[Full SQL Fiddle example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e45b/1).

Comment: Yes, this is better, but note that it won't help the case where most of the GUIDs come from the app (and who knows how they're generated).

Comment: There is no indexing on this table and I do no care if it is sequential. Eventually I will always be supplying the GUID value and this could come from a different system where it is a unique value and NOT always a GUID so I have this field as a NVARCHAR to make it a little more flexible.

Comment: To say that the index is useless is quite a stretch. Having an index that has fragmentation issues is still much better to *not* having a needed index. But still +1 for the valid solution.

Comment: So if I'm reading this correctly @Slee you are inserting Non-Sequential GUID data as NVARCHAR in a HEAP table?

Comment: I meant to say there is no indexing on THAT column in that table, there is an index - just won't be on that column

Comment: NEWSEQUENTIALID is a must have for indexed column, specially on a clustured PRIMARY KEY. I don't know the extra payload which could be an argument for not using it on all case. Of course if the guid comes from outside, there is no advantage of using NEWSEQUENTIALID but you have to check that there are really unique (if it does matter for you).

Comment: Often, yes, `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` is better, but there are times (for instance, when you're wanting to expose your keys through an API and don't want folks to be able to iterate through things) when `NEWID()` is better. And it's not at all true that indexes on that column will be "useless" - it's just that they'll get fragmented and you'll need to rebuild them periodically.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the default value for the column to `NEWID()`. Then a GUID will be created and assigned only if one hasn't already been.