# Set property, marked as primary key, is not sent to the database during insert

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, localdb

I have two databases which are 'occasionally connected'. Each entity in the database uses a Guid as primary key. This makes it easier to add records or whole object graphs from database A to database B while maintaining the correct foreign key relations.

However I now have two scenarios:

1. An entity is completely new -> it has the Guid 0000-0000...etc... In this case I want the database (or Ef6) to compute a new Guid for it, when it is stored in the database
2. An entity was originally created in database A, it has a guid like 3419-5132... in this case I want it to be added to database B as-is.

Is this scenario possible? Currently I have attributed the primary keys with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]`  and `DefaultValueSql = "newid()"` is set in the migration/database creation. This leads to the following definition in the database:

```
[TimeSlotId]          UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL
```

Which according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817235/generate-new-guid-in-sql-server-if-one-is-not-provided) should only overwrite the value if it has not been set. However, EF6 seems to be doing something funky, so the values are still changed whenever I add an entity with an existing Guid.

By using `DataContext.Database.Log` I was able to find the exact SQL query that is executed by EF6. You can clearly see that the existing value of the primary key is not sent to the database. But is, instead selected from a special table with generated keys.

```
DECLARE @generated_keys table([TimeSlotId] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[TimeSlots]([Day], [Hour], [Minute], [Schedule_ScheduleId])
OUTPUT inserted.[TimeSlotId] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, NULL)
SELECT t.[TimeSlotId]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[TimeSlots] AS t ON g.[TimeSlotId] = t.[TimeSlotId]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
-- @0: '5' (Type = Int32)

-- @1: '4' (Type = Int32)

-- @2: '33' (Type = Int32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you're looking for is something Entity Framework does not support. EF supports only two types of database-generated columns: identity columns, and computed columns. Identity columns are assumed to be set by the database when inserting a new record. Computed columns are assumed to be set by the database when inserting a new record, or modifying an existing record. In both of those cases, when a new record is added, EF will determine that it does not need to send the current value (from your program) to the database.

Depending on your needs, an approach that might work for you is to use several different context classes. In one of those classes, the column would be an identity column. In another of those classes, the column would not be an identity column. You'd choose the context you want to use based on whether you want to manually choose new values.

Another possibility is removing the database default value, and *always* setting it from your code. `newid()` in SQL has the same effect as `Guid.NewGuid()` in .NET, so you can manually generate a GUID.

Comment: That was something I was afraid of, this answer got me thinking about modifying the SQL statements myself, after a short trip on Google I came up with the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

As was able to solve this problem by creating a [Query interceptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx#BuildingBlocks) that intercepts all NonQueries that try to add an empty Guid to the database. The interceptor can be registered using `DbInterception.Add(...)`.

Note that for this to work you will need to remove the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` (or .Computed) attribute from your keys.

```
public class InsertGuidInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
    {        

        public void NonQueryExecuting(
            DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < command.Parameters.Count; i++)
            {
                var parameter = command.Parameters[i];                
                if(parameter.Value.Equals(Guid.Empty))
                {
                    //command.Parameters.Insert(i, Guid.NewGuid());
                    parameter.Value = Guid.NewGuid();
                }
            }
        }

        // Snip //
}
```

Comment: Yikes, that seems dangerous. :) I'd be worried about accidentally modifying more queries than intended with such an approach. Instead, I'd subscribe to the `SavingChanges` event (or override `SaveChanges`, whichever is easiest for you), and there, loop through all newly added entities, checking if they're of your specific type, and if so, if their key value is `Guid.Empty`.

Comment: Oh damn, that seems much simpler :)