# Column ID is GUID & assigned in SQL Server what do I set as default value in VS2012 properties windows

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, uniqueidentifier

The column `ID` is auto assigned in SQL Server. What do I set in `DATACOLUMN` properties windows for:

1. Data Type (Most probably `uniqueidentifier`)
2. Default Value (The value will be set at server)

Comment: Please Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817235/generate-new-guid-in-sql-server-if-one-is-not-provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a really good reason to use GUIDs as ID. Especially with clustered indexes they lead to extremely fragmented indexes. So think about another type, best in most cases is INT IDENTITY...

If you stay with GUID you can set the default to NEWID() or - better for indexes - to NEWSEQUENTIALID() (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).